# Ошибка в классе microtime

Tags: php

```
class PerformSpeed {
    public $start_time = microtime(true);
}
```

В чем здесь ошибка? `Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in`

Answer (score 2):

Он тебе говорит о том, что он не может предварительно инициализировать значение **не из константы**. Смысл в том, что ты заставляешь слоника указать значение до того как класс хоть раз-бы использовался. Предварительные значения могли-бы быть константой например `$start_time = 3.14159` или `$start_time = "Моя строка"`, но не как не результат вызова функции. В первом варианте точное статическое значение, в твоём это не понять что функция вернёт в runtime.

```php
class PerformSpeed {
    public $start_time;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->start_time = microtime(true);
    }
}
```